# Google Sandbox: CSV table encountered too many errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a csv file into google sandbox but I keep getting this error :

"Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 100; errors: 100. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details."

I am trying this using the add data function on sandbox, not by code or anything.

Does anyone have any solutions on how i can load the file.

I am really not sure how else to load the data.